# Are projective modules extended under surjective map

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, projective-module

Let A and B be commutative rings with unity. Given a surjective ring homomorphism
$$\pi : A \rightarrow B$$
Is every projective B module extended from a projective A module? That is given a B-projective module P, does there exist a projective A-module Q such that
$$ Q \otimes_A B = P$$

**My attempt:
Use the relation for an A-module M
$$A/I \otimes_A M \simeq M/IM.$$
I can consider B isomorphic to A/I. Then any B-module P is annihilated by I. Does this mean P is isomorphic to Q/I for a A module Q?**

Comment: Take $A=\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$=B$. $B$ is a product of two rings and thus have projective, but non-free modules (finitely generated, in fact one generated). But all projective modules over the ring of integers are free.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the ring of integers. Then the natural  ring homomorphism  $\pi:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$ is a surjective ring homomorphism. Since $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$ is a field, every $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$-module is free and so is projective. Thus, $\prod_{I} \mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$ is a projective $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$-module, where $I$ is an infinite set, and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, every projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module is free, that is, every projective  $\mathbb{Z}$-module is of the form $\bigoplus_{J}\mathbb{Z}$ for some set $J$.  Also, $(\bigoplus_{J}\mathbb{Z})\bigotimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle\cong\bigoplus_{J}\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$. But if $I$ is an infinite set we have $\prod_{I} \mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle\not\cong\bigoplus_{J} \mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$ for each set $J$.

Comment: Every Z module is not of the form $\oplus Z$, take for example infinite direct product of Z.

Comment: @user842994: But every **projective** $\mathbb{Z}$ module *is* of that form, and those are the ones at issue here.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks! I got your point. Is it possible to prove this if I restrict to finite rank projective modules?

Comment: @user842994: Prove what? Just look up a proof that every projective module over a PID is free.

Comment: I meant my initial question. Was wondering if a counterexample is possible if the projective module P taken was of finite rank.

Comment: As you say, every $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$ module is free, so an infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$ *is* isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/\langle 5\rangle$. But the indexing set $J$ will be larger than $I$.